# Change SVG style properties from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have a component that references an external SVG file:

```
<div className='logo-wrapper'>
  <object 
    type="image/svg+xml" 
    className='logo' 
    data="/images/logo.svg" 
  >
  </object>
</div>
```

Inside the SVG file, I have declared styles:

```
<style>
  .cls-1{
    fill: red;
  }
</style>
```

I need to be able to edit the styles from the parent component, say, change `.cls-1` to a green fill instead of red.

I have attempted to add classes to the parent component, however these don't seem to talk.

How does one do this?

Comment: framed documents (be it through `<iframe>`, `<object>` or `<embed>`)  don't have access to their parent document and parent doc's CSS can access their content either. You could use js to access directly the framed doc's stylesheets

Comment: * **can't** access their content either